# Disconnect event fired many times in socket.io

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I've implemented a simple chat application .But when client leaves the page or closes browser tab disconnect event is called many times. Some time twice some time thrice. Inside disconnect call back function i'm inserting chat history into database. As callback function is calling many times same chat history is inserting many times. Dont know what is the problem. Please help.

Code is like this

Server side code

```
var sys = require('sys');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');
var connection = function(){
sys.puts("Here")
var mysql = require('mysql');
var sql = mysql.createConnection({
host:'localhost',
port:3306,
user:'root',
password:'root'
});
sql.query('use chat');
sys.puts("Here" +sql)
return sql;
}
var Server = require('http').createServer(function(req, response){

sys.puts("request recieved");
response.writeHeader(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
response.write("Hello World");
var rs = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/chat.html')
sys.pump(rs,response);
});

var history = "";
var socket = io.listen(Server);

var mysql = connection();
socket.sockets.on('connection',function(client){
sys.puts("socket connected ID "+client.id);
sys.puts("session id",client.handshake.sessionID)
var username;
client.send('Welcome to chat');
client.send('Enter your name');
client.on('message',function(message){
if(!username)
{
username = message;
client.send('Welcome,' +username);
return;
}
feedback = username+' sent:'+message;
history = history + feedback + '\n';
client.send(feedback)
client.broadcast.send(feedback); 
sys.puts("History is " +history);
sys.puts("mysql" +mysql);

 client.on('disconnect',function(){
      mysql.query('insert into tblchatHistory (fldChatHistory) values ("'+history+'")',function(err){
     sys.puts("error" +err);
     history = "";
 })
  sys.puts("socket connected ID "+client.id);
 })
})
})
Server.listen(4000);
```

Client side code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket;
        socket = new io.connect("http://localhost:4000");
        var connect = false;
        socket.on('connect',function(){
            alert("connected "+socket.socket.sessionid);
            connect = true;
        })
        function chat()
        {
         socket.on('message',function(message){
            var data = message;
            var list ='<li>' +data +'</li>'

            document.getElementById("log").innerHTML +=list;
            })

        }
        function sendMsg(event)
         { 
             var entry = document.getElementById("entry");
               var msg = entry.value;
                if(event.keyCode != 13)return
                if(msg)
                    {
                       if(connect)
                           {
                             socket.emit('message',msg);
                             entry.value = "";  
                           }
                     }
         }
   </script>

<body onload="chat();">
    <h1>Chat</h1>
    <div><ul id="log"></ul></div>
    <div id="console">
        <input type="text" id="entry" onkeypress="sendMsg(event);"/>
    </div>
    <div><a href="http://localhost:8085/BillDesk/welcomeJSF.jsf" >Exit chat</a></div>
</body>
```